# Array Doubly Linked List - Function Implementation

Tags: arrays, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have just started to study data structures, and I need to understand Doubly Linked List, which is implemented by 3 arrays - Data, Next, Prev.

I want to implement Find function, which receives a value, and returns the index location of this value in the list (not in the Data array).

I know that I have a pointer that points to the first element of the list, but I struggle to return the pointer for the wanted value.

Here is my attempt in psu:

```
Find(value)
   for i=0 to D.length
      if D[i] == k
   return ?
 return -1
```

I don't know what should I return instead of the question mark (?).

For example, if my list looks like that: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`, but the array obviously doesn't have to be sorted at the same way of the list, than Find(1) will return 0, Find(3) will return 2...

Any help will be amazing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should go over the fundamentals of linked lists because you can not possibly know the length of the linked list beforehand. Therefore if you don't store the length of your list, `D.length` can not be determined until you consume the whole list.

```
function find(value)
    while pointer.next is not null (this is the indication you reached the end)
        check if pointer.value is your desired value
            return pointer
        else
            pointer = pointer.next (move your pointer)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I have tried to look for the basic implementation, but I didn't find any while using 3 arrays.
I understand what you said about the length, it makes a lot of sense now!
What is the best way to think of how to implement a Length function?
Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Java4Life There are definitely whole lot of resources you can find on the internet, just search `python linked list implementation` and you will find world of information. I am suggesting this because python is the closest language to pseudocode, making it easy to grasp.

Comment: Thank you for that, I understand the implementation using Nodes, but not using arrays - this is my weak point...